# Pull on - premise active directory data using Azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am fairly new to the Azure development world. I have been tasked to integrate an on-premise active directory with the cloud Azure SQL database( Managed Instance).

The task is to pull the identity data from on-prem AD and pump it into a SQL table in the managed SQL instance on Azure. Can ADF connect on-prem AD with cloud Azure SQL?.

Can someone show me some pointers on this? please

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Office 365 connector to pull data from the Graph API using the copy activity, your active directory needs to be integrated with Azure (Azure AD). The Service principal used to connect will need to have the User.Read.All application permission to get the information you want, otherwise you will have to authorize the service principal when the pipeline is run.

Please see the following documentation with the details how to build the pipeline with the method above:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-office-365

Answer (score 0):

Currently we are using an integration runtime with Powershell scripts to import csv files into Azure Data factory through an on prem server.  Not happy with the solution, I would be much happier with a direct connector to pull data directly from Active Directory to Azure Data factory.

Our process:
Install Integration runtime agent for on prem server - (makes this available in Azure)
Powershell scripts to pull the desired data from Active Directory into CSV files

Azure Data factory, uses the integration runtime to connect to the CSV files and import the data into Azure data factory and ETL it!